# Suggestions for documenting namespaces with Doxygen

Tags: c++, documentation, namespace

Consider several C++ classes which are all defined in a particular namespace. For cleanliness, each class is located within its own file, and are each well-documented.

For the purposes of completing the documentation with Doxygen, we'd also like to add documentation for the namespace itself.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a good best-practice solution for this? We've got a couple of options:

- A dedicated *namespace.h* file which contains only the namespace and the documentation for it. This means there is a single location to describe the namespace, but does mean having a seemingly purposeless file.
- Add the description for the namespace inside one of the class files (such as the most significant one?). This means not having to add a new file, but does make it harder to find the description if there ever is a need to modify it.

Comment: The documentation file is not "purposeless" - it is for documentation.

Comment: @BobDalgleish True. I meant "purposeless" purely in terms of code compilation and not for anyone reading it. Its presence, though beneficial in terms of documentation, does also contribute to the number of relevant header files and therefore to the "noise" which the developer needs to get their head around.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, for most libraries, you'll have a single header that includes all of the other files of interest in your library. Or at least, the majority of them.

That's a good place to document the namespace, even if that file never directly uses it. Just create an empty `namespace Name {}` declaration.